# json_prolog ERROR: init.pl: source_sink `library(my_lib)' does not exist

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to load a library of functions from a ROS package's init.pl file, json_prolog gives the error:

```
ERROR: /home/path/my_package/prolog/init.pl:19:
 source_sink `library(my_lib)' does not exist 
Warning: /home/path/my_package/prolog/init.pl:19:
 Goal (directive) failed: user:use_module(library(my_lib))
```

The init.pl file uses the code

```
:- use_module(library('my_lib')).
```

to load a file 'my_lib.pl' located in the same directory as init.pl.

When starting the package using `rosrun rosprolog rosprolog my_package`
the module gets compiled and loaded fine.

I suspect the problem is that JSONPrologNode.java uses `ensure_loaded('/home/path/my_package/prolog/init.pl')` instead of `register_ros_package(my_package)`
which is what rosprolog uses.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74266/json_prolog-error:-init.pl:-source_sink-%60library(my_lib)%27-does-not-exist/) by [zsaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6094/zsaigol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, the register_ros_package(my_package) statement should be in that package's init.pl to make sure that the package's path is added to Prolog's library search path.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6094/zsaigol/) on 2013-08-23**:
Thanks Moritz, that works fine! Although it does seem a bit inconsistent that "rosrun rosprolog rosprolog my_package" and "rosrun json_prolog json_prolog _initial_package:=my_package" work differently.